# Issue with displaying generated CV on webpage - Flask and OpenAI GPT-3.5 Turbo

Tags: python, angular, typescript, openai-api

Description:
I'm working on a Flask application that uses OpenAI GPT-3.5 Turbo to generate CVs based on a user's input. While the CV generation seems to be working fine on the server side (as confirmed by the console logs), I'm encountering issues when trying to display the generated CV on the webpage.

Problem:
The generated CV is not being displayed on the webpage, and I'm receiving a 500 Internal Server Error. The error message in the console is:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)

Code:
Here's a snippet of my Flask route handling the CV generation:

```
openai_client = OpenAI(API KEY HERE)

@app.route('/generate-cv', methods=['POST'])
def generate_cv():
    data = request.json

    # Validate required fields
    required_fields = ['jobDescription']
    for field in required_fields:
        if field not in data:
            return jsonify({'error': f'Missing required field: {field}'}), 400

    try:
        response = openai_client.chat.completions.create(
            model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
            messages=[
                {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
                {"role": "user", "content": data['jobDescription']},
            ]
        )

        # Log the response
        print(response)

        if 'choices' in response and isinstance(response['choices'], list) and response['choices']:
            first_choice = response['choices'][0]
            if isinstance(first_choice, dict) and 'message' in first_choice:
                generated_cv = first_choice['message']['content'].strip()
                return jsonify({'generatedCV': generated_cv})
            else:
                # Log unexpected response structure
                print('Unexpected response structure:', response)
                return jsonify({'error': 'Unexpected response structure'}), 500
        else:
            # Log unexpected response structure
            print('Unexpected response structure:', response)
            return jsonify({'error': 'Unexpected response structure'}), 500

    except Exception as e:
        # Log the exception
        print('Exception:', e)
        return jsonify({'error': 'CV generation failed'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Additional Information:
I'm using Angular on the frontend.
The console logs on the server side show that the CV generation is successful.

cv-generation.html code

```
<div class="border p-3 rounded-3 custom-width" style="background-color: #872341;">
    <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col text-center p-2 mb-3" style="background-color: #A9A9A9;">
            <span class="fs-3">CV Generation</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    <textarea [(ngModel)]="jobDescription" placeholder="Enter your job description"
     class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="7" style="background-color: #F3F3F3;"></textarea>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 offset-3">
          <div class="d-grid">
            <button (click)="generateCV()" style="background-color: #A9A9A9;">Generate CV</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="error" class="error-message">
  {{ error }}
</div>

<div *ngIf="generatedCV">
  <h3>Generated CV:</h3>
  <pre>{{ generatedCV }}</pre>
</div>
```

cv-generation.component.ts code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cv-generation',
  templateUrl: './cv-generation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cv-generation.component.css'],
})
export class CvGenerationComponent {
  jobDescription: string = '';
  generatedCV: string = '';
  error: string = '';

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  generateCV() {
    // Check if jobDescription is not empty
    if (!this.jobDescription.trim()) {
      console.error('Job description cannot be empty');
      return;
    }

    // Use the AuthService to call the backend API
    this.authService.generateCV({ jobDescription: this.jobDescription }).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        if (res && res.generatedCV) {
          this.generatedCV = res.generatedCV;
          this.error = ''; // Clear any previous error
        } else {
          this.error = 'Unexpected response structure';
        }
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.error = 'CV generation failed';
      }
    );
  }
}
```

`auth.service.ts` code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private apiUrl = 'apiurl goes here'; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}



  generateCV(jobData: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/generate-cv`;
    return this.http.post(url, jobData);
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any insights into what might be causing the issue and how I can modify my code to correctly display the generated CV on the webpage. Thank you!

I have implemented a Flask route that uses OpenAI GPT-3.5 Turbo to generate CVs based on user input. The CV generation appears to be successful on the server side, as confirmed by console logs. However, when attempting to display the generated CV on the webpage, I encountered a 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.